# ASP.NET GridFS get file info by Id

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, .net-6.0, gridfs

I'm trying to get `GridFSFileInfo` from GridFS database and I have a problem that it is not working while finding by id.

It is working while finding by `IdAsBsonValue` tho, here is some of my code:

```
var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.IdAsBsonValue, BsonValue.Create(ObjectId.Parse(id)));

using (var cursor = _bucket.Find(filter))
    {
        var fileInfo = cursor.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
        ...
    }
```

Code shown above is working fine but `IdAsBsonValue` is obsolete so I want to use just `Id`.

When I change first line to:

```
var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, ObjectId.Parse(id));
```

I get the following error when connecting to database: "MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionNotSupportedException: Expression not supported: x.Id."

There is property in `GridFSFileInfo` called `Id` and example shown before is working, so I have no clue what's wrong there..

Glad if anyone shares a solution :)

Im using .NET 6.0